# while(cin) cycle DOUBLE displaying

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here is the code I've written. There is the simple template PRINT function as you see..
It really works with INT type vector, but with DOUBLE it doesn't
What's the issue?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 using namespace std;

 template <typename T>
 void print (vector<T> &v) {
     for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
         cout<<v[i]<<'\t'; 
 }

 int main() {
    vector<int> vec;
    int a;
    while (cin>>a)
       vec.push_back(a);
    print(vec);
    vector<double> vec1;
    double b;
    while (cin>>b)
       vec1.push_back(b);
   print(vec1);
   return 0;
   system("pause");
}
```

I had tested it with the defined while cycle.. like while (some_integer<10) and it works, but it doesn't work without defined value of how many times it should be run
can you help me out to solve it? couldn't figure it out

Comment: useless to put `system("passe")` after `return`.

Comment: oh yeah, it have to be before 
return0;
thanks for noticing it.
but that's clearly not  the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop effectively is as follows:

```
// Continue reading things while cin is in a good state and the read succeeds (int datatype)
while (cin >> a) // ...
```

To exit that loop you read something that is non-integer (such as a letter or a .) and cin will enter a fail state.

While it is in a fail state all reads after that will fail silently.

You'll want a `cin.clear()` to clear the fail state before you attempt to read anything after it!